# Get and update user input in condition of PouchDB view

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I am building an app in which the user can enter a word. Let's say such words are car brands. Based on this car brand I want to get the number of workers in each factory. My structure in my PouchDB database is that each document represents one factory and the documents includes the number of workers and the brand name. The ID's are datetimes, so they are not helpful for the query.

This is the code I created now:

```
function getWorkers() {
                  //Get and remove current design doc
                  factoryDB.get('_design/workers').then(function (doc) {
                      return factoryDB.remove(doc)

                  //Create new design doc and put it to the db
                  }).then(function () {
                    var designWorkers = {
                          _id: '_design/workers',
                          views: {
                            'workersView': {
                              map: function(doc) {
                                  if (doc.Brand === $('#input').val()) {
                                      emit(doc.workers,doc);}
                              }.toString()
                            }
                          }
                        };
                      return factoryDB.put(designWorkers);

                    //Now start the query
                    }).then(function () {
                    return factoryDB.query('workersView')

                   //And get the results
                  }).then(function(result) {
                         console.log(result)
                  }).catch(function (err) {
                      console.log(err)
                  });
              };
```

The function is called whenever the user clicks a button. 
It is working fine for the first time. But once I change the word, it is still returning the results of the previous query. For instance:

First the user enters "Mercedes", all factory documents with "Mercedes" are returned. However, if I delete that now and instead write "Audi", I still get the documents of "Mercedes". I don't really get it, because I thought I delete the previous design document whenever the function is called again and thus the input value changes too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution to my problem.
Instead of this:

```
if (doc.Brand === $('#input').val()) {
    emit(doc.workers,doc);}.toString()
```

I passed the condition to the query:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc.Brand) {
      emit(doc.Brand,doc.workers);}
   }.toString()
.
.
.
return factoryDB.query('workersView', key: {$('#input').val()})
```

However, the remaining problem is, that it queries through all documents, whereas the previous one is already filtered in the map function (The `total_rows` attribute is larger). Perhaps someone could still give me a better solution than mine.